# Android: How to prevent Scaffolds top app bar from redrawing in Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When navigating between two Screens, where each holds a Scaffold with a TopAppBar, the TopAppBar is animated to go out of the UI and back in. (short white flash in my example, just like the button animation)

I guess this behaviour is expected as compose can't know, that these two should be treated as the same.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior without hoisting the title state to the MainNavigation composable, such that only the title is redrawn on navigation? I think in flutter there is a property named "key" on almost all widgets, is there anything like that in jetpack compose as well?

For this small example it would be fine, but when having a more complex navigation graph I'm worrying about MainNavigation getting overloaded with semantics that belong elsewhere, like loading data to display the item name ...

Code

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            UnwelcomeNavAnimationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
        composable("screen1") {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(title = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Screen 1",
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                        )
                    }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    ))
                }
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("screen2")
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Switch")
                }
            }
        }
        composable("screen2") {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(title = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Screen 2",
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                        )
                    }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    ))
                }
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("screen1")
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Switch")
                }
            }
        }
        // TODO: Add more destinations
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid the app bars from the NavHost, so you would be using a single Scaffold instead. To show them appropriately, you need to check the current route first, then show the app bar based on it.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        when (currentRoute) {
            "screen1" -> {
                TopAppBar(title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Screen 1",
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    )
                }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                ))
            }
            
            "screen2" -> {
                TopAppBar(title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Screen 2",
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    )
                }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                ))
            }
            
            else -> {
                // mandatory blank app bar to show when the start destination hasn't been yet navigated
                TopAppBar(title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "",
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    )
                }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                ))
            }
        }
    }
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "screen1",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
    ) {
        composable("screen1") {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("screen2")
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Switch")
            }
        }
        composable("screen2") {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("screen1")
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Switch")
            }
        }
        // TODO: Add more destinations
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! While this would be fine for small apps, I'm worried about the scaling of the solution; MainNavigation might get overloaded with semantics that belong elsewhere in case of a more complex navigation graph, like loading data to display the item name as title, and the content of a screen gets effectively split into multiple pieces; I would prefer a solution where each screen could define it's title and possibly other parts of the scaffold like actions, floating action button, etc...;

Comment: @Gamer2015 did you find a scalable solution?

Comment: @mrzbn No, I did not. I found one approach that uses separate NavHosts for all the components that depend on the route, but this was not nice as the update from one route to the next was not one smooth transition, but many small ones, which looked awful (eg. title updated before content has been unloaded etc..)

Comment: @Gamer2015 Good day! Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Same issue here, I have a mid sized app and this solution is not scalable.